# Laravel keeps showing 404 as if the directory or file doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to link to an edit page in my admin Laravel admin dashboard.

However for some reason when I click on the link it keeps showing the 404 page as if it didn't find the edit view.
 I tried moving the views to others directories, changing the Route, clear the route's cache but it didn't fix the issue.

The link that is supposed to take you to the edit page

```
<a href="/admin/posts/{{ $post->id }}/edit" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600">Edit</a>
```

Routes associated with the admin side of the website

```
// Admin
Route::post('admin/posts', [AdminPostController::class, 'store'])->middleware('admin');
Route::get('admin/posts/create', [AdminPostController::class, 'create'])->middleware('admin');
Route::get('admin/posts', [AdminPostController::class, 'index'])->middleware('admin');
Route::get('admin/posts/{post}/edit', [AdminPostController::class, 'edit'])->middleware('admin');
Route::patch('admin/posts/{post}', [AdminPostController::class, 'update'])->middleware('admin');
Route::delete('admin/posts/{post}', [AdminPostController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('admin');
```

[image: Directories of the project]

This is the edit function inside the AdminPostController

```
 public function edit(Post $post)
        {
            return view('admin.posts.edit', ['post' => $post]);
        }
```

Post model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

//    protected $guarded = [];
//   protected $fillable = ['title','slug'];

    protected $with = ['category', 'author'];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
    { 
        $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, fn($query, $search) =>
            $query->where(fn($query)=>
                $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                    ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            )
        );

        $query->when($filters['category'] ?? false, fn($query, $category) =>
                $query->whereHas('category', fn($query) =>
                        $query->where('slug', $category))

        );

        $query->when($filters['author'] ?? false, fn($query, $author) =>
                $query->whereHas('author', fn($query) =>
                    $query->where('username', $author))

        );
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `edit` controller action. Also, is your `$post->id` parameter valid?

Comment: @Peppermintology i edited in the edit function. And yes the $post->id is ok as in it should work because the database has a post with the propper id.

Comment: is this using a webserver or `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: @apokryfos it's using php artisan serve

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-url

Comment: Are you sure that the link is correct? Because if {{$post->id}} returns null then the link becomes admin/posts//edit which will cause a 404 error. What does the rendered link look like?

Comment: @NotDavid Why would `$post->id` ever be null?

Comment: try dumping something in the public function edit and if that success, then theres a problem in redirecting to view. Still unsure where the issue could be from

Comment: Syntactically your code looks fine. I would be inclined to believe the issue lies with `$post->id` and Laravel not being able to bind the supplied `$id` in your link to a `Post` model. Try a `dd($post);` in your `edit` action. If that still doesn't work remove the `Post` type hint in the method signature and try again.

Comment: `$post->id` could be null if the $post object does not have an id attribute. For instance if `$post` was set by querying columns without selecting id like  `$post = Post::where('id',1)->select('name')`.

Comment: @Peppermintology I tried dd() in the edit function inside of the AdminPostController however i get the 404 again. the link looks ok it looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/posts/4/edit however it points to a 404

Comment: @NotDavid the renderred link looks like this : http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/posts/3/edit which should work as expected because there does exist a post with that id

Comment: Did you try removing the `Post` type hint in your method? The `404` suggests Laravel is unable to automatically bind the `$post->id` to a `Post` model.

Comment: @Yai i tried dumping and the result was a 404 still

Comment: @Peppermintology I am not sure what you mean by removing the Post type. Could you please elaborate

Comment: Change your `edit(Post $post)` method to `edit($post)`. Keep the `dd($post);` statement in the method and then try again.

Comment: @Peppermintology it returns the id of the post ( a number that is) and when i write edit(Post $post) it returns a 404. I removed the Post and tried it again and then i receive an error of Attempt to read property "title" on string

Comment: So that tells us Laravel is unable to perform route model binding. In your `Post` model, has the `protected $primaryKey` property been overwritten to be some value other than `id`? Maybe add your `Post` model to your question.

Comment: @Peppermintology I added the post model I am not sure what you mean. Sorry im new to Laravel I was watching a tutorial and it worked in the tutorial but not to me so I am really confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247875/discussion-between-janosz--and-peppermintology).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the [`getRouteNameKey`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#customizing-the-key) method which is overriding the default key used by Laravel to identify models in your database and perform [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding).

Currently, you're telling Laravel to use the `slug` property of your `Post` model as the route model identifier, however, your link is passing an `ID`. So you either need to remove the `getRouteNameKey` method from your `Post` model which will return everything to the default `ID` route model identifier, or provide your link with a `Post` `slug`.

```
<a href="/admin/posts/{{ $post->slug }}/edit" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-600">
    Edit
</a>
```

Thereafter Laravel should be able to successfully perform route model binding.

Comment: @JanoszКрајишник Brilliant got there in the end! #party